# ASP.NET website in production goes down after while (Could not load file or assembly...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web

I have problem with web site which is made in asp.net, in dev everything works fine, but since I published it to a server, I faced next issue :

After some time some items appeard in my folder called "Temporary ASP.NET Files" and I realized when there is few stuffs web site goes down and it shows this screen:

[image]

And what I saw in my TEMP folder was next:

[image]

AND TEMPORARY SOLUTION WAS TO DELETE FILES IN THAT FOLDER BUT AFTER WHILE THEY ARE AGAIN THERE AND SITE GOES DOWN.

I TRIED WITH PREVENTING USER TO WRITE THAT FOLDER BUT THAN I GOT ANOTHER ERROR WHEN I TRY TO ACCESS MY WEBSITE, SOMETHING LIKE : 
...can not write to ... folder..

Thanks guys,
And kind of suggestion will be really great!
Thanks!

Comment: ¿What options for publishing the project you have configured? I mean, Release or Degub, excluding symbols, and also I think there is important to configure your pool as Always Running.

Comment: @Flxtr when I published my app, in Configuration: Release was selected by default, and I did not touch it..

Comment: I think there are a few things we can review. Firstable, I publish my apps in `Publish Method  FileSystem` then I copy those files to the Server, I configure the WebSite or Virtual Directory in IIS (if it is VD you have to convert to Application), then configure the pool, it must be the same versión of your Framework, I think in your case is V4.0, set `Always Running` param in pool Advance Settings, and first testing the web application in the server.One questions, is this your server or a hosting?

Comment: @Flxtr I published my app also in Publish Method File System, I set param Allways Runing in my pool Advance Settings, I just checked my project in Visual and it is .NET 4.5 and in Advance Settings .NET CLR Version there is no v.4.5 as option, there is only v4.0 and v2.0. And before it was on hosting and it worked well, but now I moved it to my server and I am facing this issues..

Comment: Try it to change framework 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `XXXXX.dll` files to the bin folder on your server.

Some times (I don't know why) some DLLs are not part of the project and you have to copy manually. If the file(s) already exists, you can replace the file with your local DLLs.

Comment: You mean I should copy all DLL files from bin folder on my dev machine to my bin folder on server machine, in case some are duplicated I should simply replace them?

Comment: Yes. First test: you can copy only those DLLs that not exists in your server. Second test, copy all the DLLs and replace existing (only DLLs, other files are not important, such as .pbd files)

Comment: I copied all dll's from my web project to my server, maybe I should copy also files from bussiness_logic part of my project?

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
1. Project Framework VS Application pool.
2. Check all Dll's if include and its framework too.
3. Check eSavez_Servis Framework.
```

Just simulate your problem one by one.

Comment: It is means the version of your project and the server doesn't match. It is the DLL

Comment: DO you mean that I am missing maybe referenced DLL's? for exaxmple if I am referencing from my web to some files in bussineslogic which is located under eSavez_servis project I should check are they also contained in my publish folder?